# Prove satisfiability of F(v,&) by induction

Tags: logic, induction

This is my question.

1) we want to prove that the set F(v,&) only contains satisfiable formulas. Explain why it is difficult to show this with a straightforward induction.

2) Instead, we have to prove a stronger statement using structural induction:
Find a variable assignment ψ, which satisfies all formulas in F(V,&) and prove this property by induction.

I know that to say a formula is satisfiable at least one interpretation should be TRUE. My answer to this question is, By induction, we assume our hypothesis true and then we prove this for n+1 step. That means for all interpretations this set F(v,&) is true. As I think the difficulty is that we cannot show this for all the possible formulas in the set F(v,&). But I am not sure about my answer. Can anyone help to understand this question? And what does it mean by the stronger statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the claim is that any statement built up from atomic propsitions and using the operators $\land $ and $\lor$ is satiafiable. Let's try and  prove this directly using structural induction:

Base: Take any atomic proposition, like $P$. Is it satisfiable? Yes, because we can set $P=T$, and of course do this for any atomic proposiion. Check!

Step: Assume that statements $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are satisfiable. Ok, so there is some truth-assignment $h_1$ that sets $\varphi$ to true and some truth-assignment $h_2$ that sets $\psi$ to true. Now, we want to show that there exists some truth-assignment $h$ that sets $\varphi \land \psi$ to true .... but now what?  Obviously we would like to somehow combine $h_1$ and $h_2$ into $h$ ... But how?  If, for example, $h_1(P) =True$ and $h_2(P)=False$ for some atomic $P$, then there is no way in which we can just 'merge' these truth-assignments together. In other words, we are really just stuck here!

OK, so let's try method 2. Let's consider the variable assignment $h$ that sets every atomic proposition to True. Now let's use structural induction to prove that for any statement $\varphi$ built up using $\land $ and $\lor$ we have that $h(\varphi) =True$:

Base: Take any atomic proposition $P$. By definition of $h$, $h(P) = True$. Check!

Step: Assume $h(\varphi)=True$ and $h(\psi) = True$ for arbitrary $\varphi$ and$\psi$. Then $h(\varphi \land \psi)=True$ and $h(\varphi \lor \psi)=True$, Check!

Ok, so we have proven that $h(\varphi)=True$ for any $\varphi$ built up from $\land$ and $\lor$. But that means that any such statement is satisfiable, and our proof is done: every statement built up from $\land$ and $\lor$ is satisfiable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation :-)

Comment: One more question. V,& are not functionally complete operators. Can I conclude it from the structural induction what you have answered?

Comment: @user2397555 given that this proof shows that all statements created from $\land$ and $\lor$ are satisfiable, it does indeed follow that $\{ \land, \lor\}$ is not functionally complete, because apprently they are unable to capture any statements that are contradictions (such as $P \land \neg P$).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Ii understood it clearly :-)

Comment: @user2397555 Great! Glad I could help! :)